# Parse...2 Devices, 1 PFInstallation?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, pfuser

Is it possible on Parse to have multiple devices associated with the same PFInstallation?  I login with my iPhone using Facebook credentials, and then do the same on my iPad, and get the same notifications delivered to each?

Comment: @hagile thank you for your informative response.  I realize I didn't ask the HOW to do this, but assumed people would be able to understand I needed to know more than simply yes or no.  But again, thank you for taking the time to comment, even though it was a useless gesture.

Comment: Aah, I can understand, you were simply not cleared to me at that time. You're referencing PFInstallation with `[PFUser currentUser]` right? In my case this is not true, I'm saving a unique for each installation. Though when a user login with same account in two different devices, there'll made separate entries for each UDIDs.